# Family Tree in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, tree, genealogy

Hello Currently I am working on a project in which I have to create family tree.
It will have almostn number of hierarchy. Whole tree should be displayed to user as well as zoom in zoom out facility should also be there . Scrolling is required.At a time user can see some specified portion of tree.When user scrolls horizontally or vertically at that time user can see other portion of tree. 
Can anyone help which approach I should follow for this? Regards, Vrunda bhattbhatt

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need to program anything, you can look into using DeepZoom for Silverlight.